# Read and write to cmd in windows

Tags: java, c++, windows, cmd

I used `system("java .....")`to run a java app in cmd with VC++ code.

The java app will run a server in the cmd,it will output info in the console.And I can also enter commands to it just like run "dir" commands in cmd.

Now I want get all the output in my program and use C++ code to write commands sent to the java app.

But I found that the `system()` won't return until I stop the java app.It's reasonable.And how to avoid it?Use Thread ?

And the biggest problem is I don't know how to get the output and write commands,can anyone give me a method?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. The java app's code can't be changed.

--------------------------------------I have made progress--------------------

```
int main()
{
    char psBuffer[256];
    FILE* output = _popen("java xxxx.jar", "rt" );

    if(output == NULL)
        return 0;

    while(fgets(psBuffer, 256, output))
    {
        printf(psBuffer);
    }

    if (feof( output))
    {
        printf( "\nProcess returned %d\n", _pclose( output ) );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I use "dir".It works perfect!But when I use java,psBuffer is always nothing,and the output of java app is normally.Is it pipe cannot redirect java's output?

---

I change my code and make some java command run perfect:

```
FILE* output = _popen("java -version 2>&1", "rt" );
```

But when it run that .jar,It failed.I read the .jar's code and find the output is create by `java.util.logging.Logger.info()`.I'm not familiar with java. How dose the `info()` work in cmd?

Thanks many!

---

Finally, I found last code above is work correctly.But origin output of java app haven't been redirect .It will display normally,but buffer is correctly received the output I want.Anyway I solved my problems.Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/

Comment: @user1781290 It's different from my problem.But I found that pipe can be used。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN article [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains how you can do it. It is quite a lot of code to go through, but will allow you to do what you want, and give you full control over it.

On the other hand, using [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) is much easier, but you don't have as much control. Depends on your exact needs as to how much code you'll be writing :).

Comment: I have found problem about pipe and have edit question.